# I'm having trouble with the script code I'm using while listing in my Laravel 8 project

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have a Laravel 8 project and I added two new tags in project. However, I've only added them in the **HTML** part for now. These new tags I added work as **HTML**, but there is a page called tag list in the project and the contents are listed according to their tags. There is a column on this listing page and there are tags.

**Previously there were only two tags:**

```
MainFeed
Normal Tag
```

**Currently there are four tags as follows:**

```
MainFeed
Normal Tag
Collection Tag
Brand Tag
```

However, I cannot show these two new tags that I added in the tag column of this tag list page.

I added these two tags inside the `create.blade.php` and `edit.blade.php` pages. I leave the HTML code of these two pages below. **The list in the tag list page I mentioned comes from the  part of the index.blade.php file.** That's why I think the reason why I can't show the tags I just added is because of that  part. But no matter what I did, I couldn't figure it out. I'm not very good at writing scripts anyway. That's why I wanted to ask you. **I also leave the  part of the index.blade.php file below. You can look at it from there.**

**create.blade.php**

```
@section('content')
    <div class="p-5">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'admin-panel/tags','method' => 'POST','files' => true)) }}
                {{ Form::token() }}
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header row mx-0">
                        <div class="mr-auto">
                            Tag
                        </div>
                        <div class="ml-auto">
                            {{ Form::submit('Create',['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-sm py-2 px-4 rounded']) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        {{ Form::label('name','Tag Name')  }}
                                        {{ Form::text('tags[name]','',['required',"class"=>"form-control form-control-sm","placeholder"=>"Name"]) }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                                        {{ Form::label('order','Tag Order')  }}
                                        {{ Form::text('tags[order]',1,['required',"class"=>"form-control form-control-sm","placeholder"=>"Name"]) }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        {{ Form::label('isMainTag','Is Main Tag')  }}
                                        <select name="tags[isMainPage]" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                                            <option value="0">Normal Tag</option>
                                            <option value="1">Main Feed Tag</option>
                                            <option value="2">Collection Tag</option>
                                            <option value="3">Brand Tag</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-2">

                                        {{ Form::label('color','Course Background Color')  }}
                                        <input  type="text" data-jscolor="{}" class="color-picker  form-control form-control-sm {{$errors->has('color') ? ' border-danger' : ''}}" id="color" name="tags[color]" value="{{old('color')}}">
                                        <small class="form-text text-danger">{!! $errors->first('color') !!}</small>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            {{ Form::label('categories','Categories')  }}
                                            {{ Form::select('categories[]',$categories->pluck('name','id') ,null , ['id'=>'tags','style'=>'width:100%','class'=>'form-control form-control-sm searchable_dropdown_multiple','multiple' => 'multiple']) }}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                {{ Form::close() }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
@section('content')
    <div class="p-5">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'admin-panel/tags/'.$tag->id,'method' => 'PUT','files' => true)) }}
                {{ Form::token() }}
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header row mx-0">
                        <div class="mr-auto">
                            Tag
                        </div>
                        <div class="ml-auto">
                            {{ Form::submit('Update',['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-sm py-2 px-4 rounded']) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        {{ Form::label('name','Tag Name')  }}
                                        {{ Form::text('tags[name]',$tag->name,['required',"class"=>"form-control form-control-sm","placeholder"=>"Name"]) }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                                        {{ Form::label('order','Tag Order')  }}
                                        {{ Form::text('tags[order]',$tag->order,['required',"class"=>"form-control form-control-sm","placeholder"=>"Name"]) }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        {{ Form::label('isMainTag','Is Main Tag', 'Collection Tag', 'Brand Tag')  }} 
                                        <select name="tags[isMainPage]" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                                            <option @if($tag->isMainPage==0) selected @endif value="0">Normal Tag</option>
                                            <option @if($tag->isMainPage==1) selected @endif value="1">Main Feed Tag</option>
                                            <option @if($tag->isMainPage==2) selected @endif value="2">Collection Tag</option>
                                            <option @if($tag->isMainPage==3) selected @endif value="3">Brand Tag</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-2">

                                        {{ Form::label('color','Course Background Color')  }}
                                        <input  type="text" data-jscolor="{}" value="{{ $tag->color  }}" class="color-picker  form-control form-control-sm {{$errors->has('color') ? ' border-danger' : ''}}" id="color" name="tags[color]" value="{{old('color')}}">
                                        <small class="form-text text-danger">{!! $errors->first('color') !!}</small>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                                            @if($tag->color!=null)
                                                <div class="border" style='background:{{$tag->color}};width: 100px;height: 100px' >     </div>
                                            @endif
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            {{ Form::label('categories','Categories')  }}
                                            {{ Form::select('categories[]',$categories->pluck('name','id') ,$tag->categories->pluck('id') , ['id'=>'tags','style'=>'width:100%','class'=>'form-control form-control-sm searchable_dropdown_multiple','multiple' => 'multiple']) }}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-12 my-5">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        {{ Form::label('type','Tag Type')  }}
                                        {{ Form::select('fields[type]',['Collection' => 'Collection Tag','Normal' => 'Normal Tag','NonPayout' => 'Non-Payout Tag'],$tag->getField('type') ?? 'Normal',["class"=>"form-control form-control-sm"]) }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        {{ Form::label('name','Brand Name')  }}
                                        {{ Form::text('fields[brand_name]',$tag->getField('brand_name'),["class"=>"form-control form-control-sm","placeholder"=>"Brand Name"]) }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        {{ Form::label('description','Brand Description')  }}
                                        {{ Form::text('fields[brand_description]',$tag->getField('brand_description'),["class"=>"form-control form-control-sm","placeholder"=>"Brand Description"]) }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        {{ Form::label('logo','Brand Logo')  }}
                                        {{ Form::file('file_fields[brand_logo]',["class"=>"form-control form-control-sm",'accept'=>'.png,.jpg,.jpeg']) }}
                                        @if($tag->getField('brand_logo')!=null)
                                            <div class="mt-2 text-center">
                                                <p>Current Logo</p>
                                                <img src="{{ $tag->getField('brand_logo')}}" height="100" width="100">
                                            </div>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                {{ Form::close() }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

**index.blade.php - @section('scripts')**

```
@section('scripts')

    <script>
        $(function() {
            var token = $("meta[name = 'csrf-token']").val();
            $('#tags_table').DataTable({
                responsive: true,
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: {url:'/admin-panel/tags/getDatatable',dataSrc:'data'},
                columns: [
                    {data: 'id'},
                    {data: 'name'},
                    {data: 'color',
                        render: function( data, type, full, meta ) {
                            return "<div style='background: "+data+";width: 50px;height: 50px' >     </div>";
                        }
                    },
                    {data: 'isMainPage',
                        render: function( data, type, full, meta ) {
                            var classTag = data ? 'text-success' : 'text-secondary';
                            var res = data ? 'MainFeed' : 'Normal Tag';
                            return  '<p  class=\"'+classTag+'\">'+res+'</p>';
                        }
                    },
                    {data: 'order'},
                    {data: 'course_number'},
                    {data: 'categories'},
                    {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
                ],
                order: [[3, 'desc'],[4,'asc']],
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                buttons: [
                    'pageLength','copy', 'excel', 'pdf',
                    {
                        extend: 'searchBuilder',
                        config: {
                            clearAll: 'Reset',
                            title: 'Search Builder Title',
                            depthLimit: 2,
                        }
                    },
                ],
            });
        });

        $('#tags_table').on('click', '.btn-delete', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            var url = $(this).data('remote');
            // confirm then
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'DELETE',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {method: '_DELETE', submit: true},
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("it Work");
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status+' '+thrownError+' Objeye Bağlı Objeler Olduğu İçin Silinemedi. Önce Bağlı Objeleri Temizleyiniz');
                }
            }).always(function (data) {
                $('#tags_table').DataTable().draw(false);
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

**The tag of the content I marked in red in the screenshot is actually Collection Tag, but as I mentioned in my problem above, I can't show it. It lists it as MainFeed instead.**
[image]

**TagController - getDataTable**

```
    {
        return DataTables::of(Tag::select(['id','name','color','order','isMainPage']))
            ->addColumn('course_number', function (Tag $tag) {
                return count($tag->courses);
            })->addColumn('categories', function (Tag $tag) {
                return $tag->categories->implode('name',',');
            })
            ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                $btn = '<a href="/admin-panel/tags/'.$row['id'].'" class="edit btn btn-info btn-sm">View</a>';

                $btn = $btn.'<a href="/admin-panel/tags/'.$row['id'].'/edit" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>';

                $btn = $btn.'<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-remote="/admin-panel/tags/'.$row['id'].'" class="edit btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-delete">Del</a>';

                return $btn;

            })->make(true);
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a PHP problem, a JS problem, or an HTML problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase It's a JS issue if you ask me. Because the list on the tag list page comes from the JS part of index.blade.php. However, I don't know how to list these two tags from there.

Comment: Looks like `var res = data ? 'MainFeed' : 'Normal Tag';` decides which "tag" to show based on that `data`. You'd need to adjust this

Comment: @brombeer So how can I do this? can you help me with this? I'm really not good at JS at all.

Comment: What response did you get from `admin-panel/tags/getDatatable` ? Can you share the method content here?

Comment: What does `data` contain here?

Comment: @SemihSAHIN What exactly do I need to share? Is it the result of typing `http://localhost/admin-panel/tags/getDatatable` in the address bar?

Comment: See what the route `admin-panel/tags/getDatatable` corresponds to in your route file (`web.php`). Then find the relevant method and share it's content here.

Comment: @SemihSAHIN I looked from web.php as you said and saw it went to **TagController**. I found the **getDataTable function** in **TagController**. Since the function is long in the comment section, I edit my question and add the function at the end so that you can look at it more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
{data: 'isMainPage',
    render: function( data, type, full, meta ) {
        var classTag = data ? 'text-success' : 'text-secondary';
        var res = data ? 'MainFeed' : 'Normal Tag';
        return  '<p  class=\"'+classTag+'\">'+res+'</p>';
    }
},
```

Change it:

```
{data: 'isMainPage',
    render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
        var classTag = data ? 'text-success' : 'text-secondary';
        var res = '';
        switch (parseInt(data)) {
            case 0:
                res = 'Normal Tag';
                break;
            case 1:
                res = 'Main Feed Tag';
                break;
            case 2:
                res = 'Collection Tag';
                break;
            case 3:
                res = 'Brand Tag';
                break;
            default:
                res = 'Normal Tag';
                break;
        }
        return  '<p  class=\"' + classTag + '\">' + res + '</p>';
    }
},
```